# rails 4 redirect back with new params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Is it possible to redirect back to the referring url with a new param in the query string?

something like this:

```
redirect_to :back, custom_param='foo'
```

Comment: when you say `:back` do you mean back to where the user came from or some action named `back?`

Comment: the first one ==> :back

Comment: edited the question to make the meaning more clear.

Comment: Its 2015 surely there has to be a better way to do this!

Comment: It's 2016 surely there has to be a better way to do this!

Comment: It's 2018 surely there has to be a better way to do this!

Comment: It's 2019 surely there has to be a better way to do this!

Comment: It's 2020 surely there has to be a better way to do this!

Comment: It's 2021 surely there has to be a better way to do this!

Comment: It's 2022 surely there has to be a better way to do this!

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
# get a URI object for referring url 
referrer_url = URI.parse(request.referrer) rescue URI.parse(some_default_url)
                    # need to have a default in case referrer is not given


# append the query string to the  referrer url
referrer_url.query = Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query(referrer_url.query).
                    # referrer_url.query returns the existing query string => "f=b"
                    # Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query converts query string to hash => {f: "b"}
                    merge({cp: 'foo'}).
                    # merge appends or overwrites the new parameter  => {f: "b", cp: :foo'}
                    to_query
                    # to_query converts hash back to query string => "f=b&cp=foo"



# redirect to the referrer url with the modified query string
redirect_to referrer_url.to_s
                    # to_s converts the URI object to url string
```

Comment: One gotcha here. `Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query(referrer_url.query)` returns a hash with stringified keys. So if your `referrer_url` has `cp=bar` as its current query string. The query of the url will be: `cp=bar&cp=foo`. Change `Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query(referrer_url.query)` to `Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query(referrer_url.query).symbolize_keys.` or `Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query(referrer_url.query).stringify_keys` as needed

Answer (score 6):

You can put it in session and then redirect back

```
session[:somekey] = value
redirect_to :back
```

Comment: When you use session the values in session remains there between requests.

Comment: yes but i need to put the params in the link, i need some like this: http://localhost:3000/?locale='pt'

Answer (score 3):

Another approach could be to pass it via "flash" (it goes away automatically after the redirect request):

```
flash[:somekey] = 'some value'
redirect_to :back
```

However, as one of my colleagues noted, a better way is probably to return it as a query param, to keep it stateless and distinguish the two URLs. It seems there isn't a nice, built-in Rails way to do that, which makes me wonder what else is wrong with this approach.